# Where to ask "Examples of {technology} in production?" SO? Programmers? Non-SE?

Tags: discussion, subjective, example-questions

Sometimes it helps to see examples what others have built to understand a technology or to be inspired.  I've seen a few of this style of question on SO before, but it strikes me as somewhat subjective.

Is it permissible to solicit for production/live examples?  Spiels like "it can do X, Y, and Z" mean little if no one has use for those.

Comment: You likely just need recommendations on some good open source projects that you could browse the source code of...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That strikes me as a "list of X" question, so it's likely to get closed anywhere you ask it.  You might try asking in one of the chat rooms specific to your {technology}.